# Solving $I=\int_{0}^{1} x^2 J_0(k_nx) \ dx.$

Tags: integration, proof-verification, bessel-functions

> I am trying to solve, $$I=\int_{0}^{1} x^2 J_0(k_nx) \ dx.$$

My attempt:

I choose make the substitution $u=k_nx$, which has led to,
$$I=\frac{1}{k_n^3}\int_{0}^{k_n} u^2 J_0(u) \ du.$$ Looking at an integral table, I see that $$\int x^2J_0(x) \ dx=x^2J_1(x)-\phi(x) \ \ \text{where} \ \ \phi(x)=\frac{\pi x}{2}\left(J_1(x)\cdot H_0(x)-J_0(x)\cdot H_1(x)\right).$$ Unfortunately, I think this is beyond the scope of my course, as I have not heard of the Sturve function $(H_v(x))$.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: You very much need to define what $k_n$ is.  I suspect it is either a zero of $J_0(x)$ or its derivative.  If so, you might be able to get a closed form.

Comment: Indeed, $k_n$ is the $n^{th}$ root of $J_0(x)$. Is that sufficient detail for this proof? Does this help determine a closed form?

Answer (score 1):

As the problem is set, I do not see how you could avoid Struve functions for the integral.

For the antiderivative, what you could use is 
$$I=\int u^2 J_0(u) \, du=\frac{u^3}{3}  \, _1F_2\left(\frac{3}{2};1,\frac{5}{2};-\frac{u^2}{4}\right)$$ which of no much interest since it simplifies to
$$I=\frac{1}{2} u ((2 u-\pi  \pmb{H}_0(u)) J_1(u)+\pi  \pmb{H}_1(u) J_0(u))$$ you already found in the integral table.

Comment: I have added an edit. Is this what you mean? Any advice is appreciated as I am unfamiliar with Sturve functions, yet have a question given to me that relies on their use.